# Oracle: Migrating a col. with values, nulls and 0s

Tags: oracle, null, data-conversion

I'm migrating data from one db to another.

I have a numeric col. that contains some values, some 0s and some nulls.  My gut feeling is to convert all the 0s to NULLs.  This will store an optional, user-provided number.

Any reason NOT to convert all the 0s to NULLs?

Comment: No details given. Its as vague as asking "I need to store some data. What datatype should I use ?"

Answer (score 1):

There are [issues with indexing NULLs](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2008/01/23/indexing-nulls-empty-spaces/) (in that generally they aren't).

If you mean 0, use 0. Using NULL instead will change your sort order and affect arithmetic (and comparison). NULLs are used to indicate there is no value. Using them as a replacement for 0 (which **is** a value) is a good example of micro-optimization driving your design rather than.. the design.

Comment: This col. would not be indexed, and in fact is rarely used - about 50 out of 15k records have data.  But at some point the application changed, and 0 were stored instead of NULL.

Comment: The point remains: I would be more interested in what the data means rather than any perceived benefits of storing NULL instead of 0.

Comment: I did discover that count(field) returns only the count of non-nulls, so that might be a good reason not to leave 0's in there - the values are dollar amounts, so it may be useful to do averages, counts, etc on the data in the future.

Answer (score 1):

One reason not to convert zeros to null is that they mean different things mathematically.

1. If I have the numbers (0,10,20), the average of those is 10. If I convert the zero to null, the average becomes 15.
2. If I have the numbers 5 and 0, added together they make 5. Turn the 0 to a null and added together they make NULL.
3. The default ordering of null,-5 and 10 is (-5, 10, NULL) unless you use NULLS FIRST in which case you get (NULL, -5, 10). Obviously the ordering with zero is (-5, 0, 10).

So if these are numbers, used for numeric functions, then you need to use NULLs and zeros in accordance with the application requirements (which you don't give).

Maybe if you gave some indication of what the number represents you may get a useful answer.